# Customize "Waiting for Approval" message text

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

In a content approval process, SharePoint puts a nice message in a yellow warning box to the user saying: "Waiting for Approval: Visitors can't see recent changes until they are approved. *Approve it*."

Is there any way to alter or edit this text? Why does the "Approve It" option show up for users that are not listed as approvers?

Running SharePoint Online through Office 365 E3. SharePoint Designer an option.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. Though nothing happens when users (with no approval rights) click on it, it still annoys.

I would alter it with below code. I have used hide(), you can alter the text too

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
        if($("#pageStatusBar").length > 0)
        {
            $("#pageStatusBar A").hide();
        }
}, 2000);
```

One more easier option if you want to just hide is by CSS which is far simpler & doesn't add the JS overhead.

```
#pageStatusBar A
{
    color: #fff19d !important;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to further modify the banner.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.ratings.js','SP.ClientContext',function()
                    {
                        setTimeout(function(){ 
                            if($("#pageStatusBar").length > 0)
                            {
                                var existingText = $("#status_1_body").text();

                                    if(existingText.indexOf("page checked out") == -1)
                                    {                                       
                                        $(".ms-status-title").text("The article below is only visible to you,");
                                        $("#status_1_body").text("the submitter, and the validators that are currently reviewing the article. You’ll receive an automated message once this article is approved.");
                                    }
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    });
```

If not interested in above snippet, you can just clear the message and leverage SP.UI.Status namespace for doing it using SPO way rather than customized JQuery way..